# Where is the parabolic paraboloid?

Tags: quadrics

In theory, any quadric surface can, through a series of translations and linear transforms, be converted to $f(X)+g(Y)+h(Z)=C$, where $f(X)=X^2$ (except in the case of the imaginary ellipse, where $f(X)=-X^2$), $g(Y)$ and $h(Z)$ may be positive square, negative square, negative linear or zero functions, and $C$ is either $0$ or $1$. By my reckoning, doing these transforms would result in eleven distinct possible surfaces (counting cases that differ only by $C$'s value as not distinct). These are:

$X^2+Y^2+Z^2=C$, the real ellipsoid (point if $C=0$)

$X^2+Y^2-Z^2=C$, the hyperboloid of one sheet (double cone if $C=0$) about the $Z$-axis

$X^2-Y^2-Z^2=C$, the hyperboloid of two sheets (double cone if $C=0$) about the $X$-axis

$-X^2-Y^2-Z^2=C$, the imaginary ellipsoid (point if $C=0$)

$X^2+Y^2-Z=C$, the elliptic paraboloid

$X^2-Y^2-Z=C$, the hyperbolic paraboloid

$X^2-Y-Z=C$, which is unnamed but by analogy would be the parabolic paraboloid

$X^2+Y^2=C$, the elliptic cylinder (line if $C=0$)

$X^2-Y^2=C$, the hyperbolic cylinder (pair of intersecting planes if $C=0$)

$X^2-Y=C$, the parabolic cylinder and

$X^2=C$, the pair of parallel (coincident if $C=0$) planes.

These aren't necessarily the canonical forms of course, but they do highlight an apparent gap in the literature. I have yet to find any mention of a quadric surface with one square term and two linear terms, the parabolic paraboloid in the list. Does it make sense to consider this surface? Can it be reckoned in terms of the others? What does it look like? And where can I find literature on the subject?

Comment: What do you mean by the unusual expression "parabolic paraboloid" ? The "true", paraboloid, obtain by the revolution of a prabola around its axis ? This one is a particular case of an elliptic paraboloid...

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you can turn the yz plane by 45 degrees and have a new coordinate y' such that x^2-y'=c , a parabolic cylinder.

Comment: That makes an absurd amount of sense and I'm kicking myself for not having thought of it. Thank you @OfekGillon .

Comment: You're welcome! @NoName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X^2-Y-Z=C$ (my "parabolic paraboloid") can be rotated into $X^2-Y=C$ (the parabolic cylinder).

Thanks to Ofek Gillon for untangling the knot I had tied my brain into.